# How to ignore any blanks or spaces when sorting two lists together in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one big nested list here which is simplified because the actual one has several dozens of lists:

```
 bigNestedList = [["d", "c", "a", "b", "e"],[4,"",8,9,""],.....]
```

For simplicity I shall split them into two separate lists:

```
list1 = ["d", "c", "a", "b", "e"]
list2 = [4,"",8,9,""]
```

I want to sort list1 with respect to list2 in ascending order. However the problem arises with the blank spaces in list2.

I have tried to remove the blanks in list2 and sort them:

```
list2_tmp = list(filter(None, list2))

list2, list1 = zip(*sorted(zip(list2_tmp, list1)))
```

However the final sorted lists are not correct

```
list1
Out[164]: ('d', 'c', 'a')

list2
Out[165]: (4, 8, 9)
```

The correct answer should be (d, a, b) and (4, 8, 9).

But this would mean I would have to delete the elements in list1 corresponding to the index of the blanks in list2. However I have to use the original data from list1 later on in my code aswell.

Hence how do I sort these two lists in the most efficient manner by ignoring any blanks and not resorting to creating extra lists that use up more memory? (I have several dozens of lists to sort wrt to list1 later on aswell)

Comment: Wait, so are you trying to get the index of list1 where list2 is? And if the list 2 value is greater than the length of list1 you just loop around? I don't really understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's not clear how you want to "sort". In the correct answer you gave no elements have changed order. You just removed some elements from `list1`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could zip the two lists together, remove the entries with spaces, and sort the remainder:

```
sorted(pair for pair in zip(list2, list1) if pair[0] != '')
```

This produces a list of tuples, so you'd need to extract the second elements:

```
[b for a, b in sorted(pair for pair in zip(list2, list1) if pair[0] != '')]
```

Demo:

```
>>> [b for a, b in sorted(pair for pair in zip(list2, list1) if pair[0] != '')]
['d', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way with `itertools.compress()` + `filter()` functions:

```
import itertools

list1 = ["d", "c", "a", "b", "e"]
list2 = [4, "", 8, 9, ""]
new_lst2, new_lst1 = zip(*sorted(zip(filter(None, list2), itertools.compress(list1, list2))))

print(new_lst1)   # ('d', 'a', 'b')
print(new_lst2)   # (4, 8, 9)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.compress

Comment: I didn't use `compress` because you need the `list2` elements *again* when sorting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, nothing strange ... that's why you've got 5 time as much upvotes. I've posted an alternative approach